# Javascript document write overwriting page?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I'm very new with javascript.

I'm trying to create a  tag using document.write (with Wordpress) to add a style that hides images before they are preloaded. I've had to resort to writing a Javascript style to hide the images before they are loaded via CSS. I don't want to actually write it into the CSS file incase the user has Javascript disabled and then the images would never show.

I'm trying to get this code to work:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    document.write('<style type="text/css"> .preload img { display: none; } </style>');
    $('#body-wrap').preloadThis();
});
```

But, it is just overwriting the whole page and making it go blank. How can I stop this? I want to add the  tag to the   without removing the page. Tried using 'return', no luck.

Sorry, I'm a novice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `document.write()` after the page has finished loading [implicitly calls `document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write#notes), which creates a new page.  You should generally avoid `document.write()` and stick to proper DOM creation techniques, or use jQuery's shorthand creation methods:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('<style type="text/css"> .preload img { display: none; } </style>')
        .appendTo("head");
    $('#body-wrap').preloadThis();
});
```

---

I'm assuming you can't edit the HTML or CSS files that are loaded by the page to include this rule?  If that's the case, and you want these styles applied before the page finishes loading, take `document.write()` out of the jQuery ready handler:

```
// write() before the document finishes loading
document.write('<style type="text/css"> .preload img { display: none; } </style>');
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#body-wrap').preloadThis();
});
```

This will write the `<style>` tag immediately after the currently executing `<script>` tag.  Hopefully, this is in your `<head>` element as `<style>` is invalid anywhere else, although all browsers should parse it OK either way.

Comment: Same problem as using .hide().. when the images are cached (loaded on previous page load) they are visible before the jQuery is applied. This causes the image to appear before being hidden, then faded in by the preload plugin.. Trying to get rid of the flicker before it is hidden.

Comment: @Matthew: I've updated my answer.  It's safe to use `document.write` if the page hasn't finished loading, so if you take it out of jQuery's document ready handler you should be OK.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add `<style>` tag, you can just hide them with jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.preload img').hide();
    $('#body-wrap').preloadThis();
});
```

Don't know how your `preloadThis()` function works, but I guess it loads images and removes `.preload` class from `img` container. If it indeed works like that, this code will not help you - images will stay hidden.

Comment: No it finds all images within .preload and fades them in. The problem with .hide() is that it isn't kicking in fast enough when the images are cached, so the images are visible for a split second before they are hidden, then they are faded in. Doesn't look great.