# onMouseOver text replaces entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu I'm trying to make, where when you hover over a link a smaller menu appears. 
I'm using onmouseover on the a tag to display the smallmenu tag I have styled in CSS.

The problem is when I hover over the link, the entire page is replaced with the smallmenu. Here's my code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>JS3</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
            }
            menu {
                font-size: 18px;
                background-color: #E0E0E0;
                border-radius: 5px;
                width: 400px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            a:link, a:visited {
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #E0E0E0;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 80px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            a:hover {
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #CCCCCC;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 80px;
            }
            smallmenu {
                font-size: 12px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                width: 150px;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <menu>
                <a href="#" onmouseover="document.write('<smallmenu>test</smallmenu>');">| Home |</a> <a href="#">| Link 1 |</a> <a href="#">| Link 2 |</a>
                <smallmenu style="visibility: hidden">test</smallmenu>
            </menu>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't use document.write() because it clear all of your content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document.write writes to the document. Not appending anything, what you want.

But, this problem can be solved using css only.

You html will look like this:

```
<a href="#">Link
     <smallmenu>test</smallmenu>
</a>
```

And your CSS

```
a > smallmenu {
    display: none;
}
a:hover > smallmenu {
    display: block;
}
```

So, when you hover over you link the child `smallmenu` will become visible. 
You have to improve this example a bit, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.write` after a page load will flush the HTML buffer and replace the content of your document.

You have a well explained solution here : [Javascript document write overwriting page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520440/javascript-document-write-overwriting-page)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just set the visibility of the smallmenu tag to visible instead of writing into the document.