# Create a table inside script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How do I create a table inside the script tag without going to another page? I am currently using the **document.write()** function but it opens a new page but i want it to stay on the page as i click my button? here is my current code:

```
 $( "#searchVehicleDesc" ).button().click(function( event ) {

                document.write('<fieldset>');
                document.write('<legend>Dashboard<\/legend><br>');
                document.write('<table border="1" width="650">');
                document.write('<tr bgcolor=#c0c0c0>');
                document.write('<td width=100 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Vehicle Name<\/b><\/font><\/td>');
                document.write('<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Service Type<\/b><\/font><\/td>');
                document.write('<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Others<\/b></\font><\/td>');
                document.write('<td width=100 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference No.<\/b><\/font><\/td>');
                document.write('<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference Date<\/b><\/font><\/td>');
                document.write('<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference Type<\/b><\/font><\/td>');
                document.write('<\/tr>');
                document.write('<\/table>');
                document.write('<\/fieldset>');


  });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript document write overwriting page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520440/javascript-document-write-overwriting-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
var myTable =
    '<fieldset>' +
        '<legend>Dashboard</legend></br>' +
        '<table border="1" width="650">' +
            '<tr bgcolor=#c0c0c0>' +
                '<td width=100 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Vehicle Name</b></font></td>' +
                '<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Service Type</b></font></td>' +
                '<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Others</b></font></td>' +
                '<td width=100 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference No.</b></font></td>' +
                '<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference Date</b></font></td>' +
                '<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference Type</b></font></td>' +
            '</tr>' +
        '</table>' +
    '</fieldset>';

$( "#searchVehicleDesc" ).button().click(function( event ) {
    $(document.body).append(myTable);
});
```

Notice that you don't have to escape forward slashes (`/`) in JavaScript strings.

You can also make the table HTML a lot shorter, while also making it easier to maintain, by using **[CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)**:

In your JavaScript:

```
var myTable =
    '<fieldset>' +
        '<legend>Dashboard</legend></br>' +
        '<table>' +
            '<tr>' +
                '<td class="large">Vehicle Name</td>' +
                '<td class="small">Service Type</td>' +
                '<td class="small">Others</td>' +
                '<td class="large">Reference No.</td>' +
                '<td class="small">Reference Date</td>' +
                '<td class="small">Reference Type</td>' +
            '</tr>' +
        '</table>' +
    '</fieldset>'
```

CSS file:

```css
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr{ /* You could use just `tr{` here (leave out `table `), I just prefer this */
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
table tr td{ /* Same here, for `td{` */
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.large{
    width: 100px;
}
.small{
    width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Aye, you're right. I'm also going to add a scc alternative to all those `<font>` tags.

Comment: @ Cerbrus: Why stop there? There's also the `<b>` tags, `width` and `align` attributes, `bgcolor`, `border`... ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That should be all of it :-)

Comment: how do i append it to an html element?

Comment: @fanboime12: Assuming something like: `<div id="myElement"></div>`, you can do it like this: `$('#myElement').append(myTable);`

Answer (score 2):

`document.write()` will overwrite current content in your page. You can use `.append()` instead:

```
$("#searchVehicleDesc" ).button().click(function( event ) {
     $(document.body).append('<fieldset><legend>Dashboard</legend><br /><table border="1" width="650"><tr bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><td width="100" align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Vehicle Name</b></font></td><td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Service Type</b></font></td><td width="80" align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Others</b></font></td><td width="100" align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference No.</b></font></td><td width="80" align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference Date</b></font></td><td width="80" align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference Type</b></font></td></tr></table></fieldset>');
});
```

Comment: $("#searchVehicleDesc" ).button() what it means?

Comment: @sudharsan jQuery UI syntax for a button

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery's append() function.

```
$( "#searchVehicleDesc" ).button().click(function( event ) {

                $('#searchVehicleDesc').append('<fieldset>');    
  });
```

see jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L2DEE/

Answer (score 1):

You **should** create DOM elements in JS using the `document.createElement()` method. Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

You could also append the html string like `document.getElementById('target_container').innerHTML('<div><-- your über long html string--></div>');`

In case of jQuery you can simply append your html string to an object, like `$('#target_container').html('<div><-- your über long html string--></div>');`

Answer (score 0):

That is because each time you call `document.write`, you are overriding the document.

Concat all the strings and then append it to some container.

Comment: So does that mean i have to use one document.write only? and concat all  tags inside it?

Comment: @fanboime12: It means not using it at all (or only in very limited situations) in modern pages.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using jQuery, there are lots of methods you can use to add content to an existing page:

- `html`
- `append`
- `appendTo`
- `prepend`
- `prependTo`
- `before`
- `insertBefore`
- `after`
- `insertAfter`

...and others. They're all covered, with examples, in the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Answer (score 0):

Just make a div and put your table in it.

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

your script should be something like this:

```
var table = '<fieldset>'+
        '<legend>Dashboard</legend><br>'+
        '<table border="1" width="650">';
```

... and so on... 
Then simply append to your container.

```
 $("#container").append(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
var myObj, txt;
txt += "<table>"
                myObj = JSON.parse(text);
                        for (x in myObj.issues) {
                            console.log(myObj.issues[x])
                            txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj.issues[x].key + "</td>";
                            txt += "<td>" + myObj.issues[x].fields.summary + "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        txt += "</table>"
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```